# Jumping between full screens in Yosemite?

Tags: shortcut, fullscreen

I like having many full screens open (in the same ‘space’), but it bothers me that I have to press CMD+right twice to get from 1 to 3; it should be possible to jump directly to 3 with a shortcut like ctrl+3. Or is it?

PS. Sorry, I meant: can one jump between *spaces* within the same desktop?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can certainly do so.

- Go to **Settings > Keyboard**
- From there select **Shortcuts**
- **Mission Control**
- Tick the boxes for the Desktops you want.

[image: Shortcuts]

---

EDIT: One quick way to to move is to <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> to switch between open applications.  Otherwise, you can submit feedback to Apple.

[OS X 10.11 El Capitan](https://www.apple.com/osx/elcapitan-preview/) will feature having a **Split View** which may be more convenient when rolled out.

Comment: Also note that if you have an extended keyboard, by default the ctrl/number you see is for the numbers above QWERTY, not the NumPad [10-key]. You need to specifically re-enter the NumPad numbers if that's what you wish to use. Also note that Fullscreened apps don't have Desktop numbers & cannot be directly accessed in this way. You need to 'number' to the nearest screen, then 'arrow' to the one you need.

Comment: @bjbk: Thanks! I got my terminology mixed up, though, and meant to ask: can one jump between spaces within one desktop? I tried used several desktops before, but found it unpractical with full screens, as these use other spaces than the main desktops.

Comment: Thanks to both of you for clearing that up. Use Command + Tab to quickly jump between full screen apps.